# ResultSet.next always false, table populated

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, resultset

My table:

```
create table ranking (rennId int not null, fId int not null, pos int not null, CONSTRAINT key PRIMARY KEY (rennId,fId))
```

My java code:

```
try {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    ResultSet ret = con.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from ranking");
    while (ret.next())
        System.out.println("test");
} catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Manual test:

```
sql> select * from ranking
[2017-06-13 03:21:59] 3 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 52ms (execution: 45ms, fetching: 7ms)
```

Tested as standalone
Only occurs on this table

Comment: I believe it is the contract of try-with-resources to guarantee closing the resource specified in the try clause, after the expression finishes executing. I believe that the result set is also being closed at the end of the try block, hence calling next() returns false, because nothing is there

Comment: @user7790438 But the loop over the result is entirely _inside_ the `try` block.  Why would you expect any resources to be closed at that point?

Comment: Are the names of the tables in the create query and select query different in purpose?

Comment: @SHG sorry copy paste fail, they are the same

Comment: @user7790438 next on a closed result throws an error, even tested if it realy does, and ye its not the case here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was an issue combined with DataGrip.
This code actualy selects all entries created within this application, but ignores all entries created via DataGrip.
Seems to be related to a combined Primary Key